# NTFS Partition Not Mounting Properly, Cannot Execute Despite Ownership

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, fstab, ntfs-3g

I'm trying to execute a script located on an NTFS partition that I own.

I own the mount point, which is `~/Migration`.

`ls -l` in the directory where the mount point is contained shows me

```
 drwxrwxrwx 1 technomage technomage   4096 Sep 30 18:04 Migration
```

Despite being the owner of the entire structure, from the mount point and onwards, and having rwx privileges, it  prevents me from executing this script, `startup.sh`. Bash gives me the following error:

```
bash: ./startup.sh: Permission denied
```

In the directory that contains the script, `ls-la` shows me:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 technomage technomage 4.0K Oct  1 12:51 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 technomage technomage 4.0K Oct  1 12:51 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 technomage technomage 1.9K Oct  1 12:51 startup.sh
```

Still I cannot execute `startup.sh`.

I know that permissions on NTFS partitions in linux can be somewhat finnicky, so I went into the `/etc/fstab` and set the privileges, owners and masks as best as I could:

```
 UUID=6F537BB96F6E0CBC /home/technomage/Migration ntfs-3g rw,exec,user,umask=000,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

I then proceeded to `sudo umount Migration`, followed by reloading the fstab file configuration with `sudo mount -a`. The remounting is successful.

Despite all of this, I still cannot execute the script despite even using root.

The `mount | grep sda6` command shows me the following, which tells me somehow, that the partition isn't mounting properly or using the configurations I gave it:

```
/dev/sda6 on /home/technomage/Migration type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,user)
```

I'm running Debian Jessie, and even went into stretch's repository to get the latest version of the `ntfs-3g` driver, thinking it was some kind of bug.. no dice.

I'm not quite sure what's wrong. Please show me how I misconfigured how I mount my NTFS partition? I need total access to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your options right in `/etc/fstab`, but the order matters; `exec` has to come *after* `user` because `user` imposes `noexec` (among others). So your `/etc/fstab` entry should look like this:

```
UUID=6F537BB96F6E0CBC /home/technomage/Migration ntfs-3g rw,umask=000,uid=1000,gid=1000,user,exec 0 0
```

After the change to `/etc/fstab`, unmount the drive then `sudo mount -a` and try again.

Also, make sure your `uid` and `gid` are correct (by executing the command `id` when logged in with your user).

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for this answer. Out of all the `fstab` tutorials I've read, none of them mention this one small but very important detail.